# Is there a limit for Pandas Apply for many files?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, text-processing

I have 10.000 CSV datasets for my project. I need to preprocess all of those datasets but Pandas can only process five at one run? Here is my code for opening all files.

```
path = "./for_processing"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if not file.startswith('.')]

index_cleaned_news = 0
for file in files:
     NEWS_DATA = pd.read_csv(path+"/kompas/clean_news"+str(index_cleaned_news)+".csv")
     #Process here
     NEWS_DATA.to_csv(path+"/process_kompas/preprocess_news"+str(index_cleaned_news)+".csv")
     index_cleaned_news = index_cleaned_news+1
```

Here is a screenshot when I try to run the code
[image: It limits only 5 iterations]

Anybody know how to fix this or is it a rule from Pandas? Thank you

Comment: What is the value of `index_cleaned_news` at the end of the loop? And what is the value of `len(files)`?

Comment: since it stops in the 5th iteration the value of the index is 4 (there is only 5 output files). for every file, the length of the file is various between 5 lines to 25 lines each CSV

Comment: What is the `len(files)`? You are using `os.listdir(path)`, but then you seem to be reading the csv's with an aditional subdir (`/kompas`). `os.listdir()` does not scan directories recursively.

Comment: And I don't realy get why you are using `for file in files` and then never use `file`... Either use something like `for index_cleaned_news in range(len(files)):` or just use the file variable in your `pd.read_csv()`...

Comment: Thanks I just realize I never used the variable files. I solved it already by using the variable in 'pd.read_csv()'

Comment: I don't understand the question: Are you using chained `apply`s and come to a limit (like `df.apply(...).apply(...).apply(...).apply(...)...`)?